# Using Deep Clone in Controller Extension

Tags: apex, visualforce

So what I need to do is use deep clone to clone my `Opportunity` object and then update the new cloned `RecordTypeName__c` field to something.

Can someone help me achieve this? Well I actually created a DeepClone method but I don't know If I am doing the right thing. Can someone guide me with this one? Thanks in advance

```
public class LPGVSPOpportunityCloneControllerExt {
    public Opportunity opp { get; set; }
    public String opportunityID {get; set;}

    public LPGVSPOpportunityCloneControllerExt (ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
        opportunityID =(String)ctrl.getRecord().get('Id');
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        }
        query += 'Id FROM Opportunity where Id=: opportunityID ';
        opp = (Opportunity)Database.query(query);
    }

    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.LPG_SAP_Opportunity_Clone_Fields.getFields();
    }

    public void DeepClone(){
        opp = [Select id, RecordTypeName__c from Opportunity where Id = :opportunityID];
        List<Opportunity> opportunityList = new List<Opportunity>();
        opportunityList.add(opp);
        List<Opportunity> newOpportunityList = opportunityList.deepclone();
        insert opportunityList;
        System.debug('###'+newOpportunityList[0].Id);
    }
}
```

and also how can I test if my clone works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're essentially creating an opportunity with just one field populated; it'll probably fail to insert. You can probably get away with this instead:

```
public void deepClone() {
    Opportunity temp = opp.clone(false, false, false, false);
    // Change any fields in temp if need be.
    // Finally:
    insert temp;
}
```

As for testing, you basically need to create a new opportunity, instantiate your controller using that new opportunity, call your method, and then verify that a new record was created.

Comment: what does that four false means?

Comment: and for example opp.RecordTypeName = ''. How can I store it's new Opportunity ID? @sfdcfox

Comment: See [sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm), but they are: preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadOnlyTimeStamps, and preserveAutonumber. The first clears out the Id field, the second doesn't clone related objects, the third option clears out CreatedDate/LastModifiedDate/etc fields, and the fourth clears out any auto-number fields.

Comment: @JMDF Your method does "do" anything right now, so you'll want to figure out what you'd like to do. In my example code, `temp.id` will have the new opportunity's Id once the insert completes.

Comment: so for example  Opportunity temp = opp.clone(false, false, false, false);
     temp.RecordTypeID = opp.RecordTypeID;
    insert temp;
I tried to do that. That means that it stores it's new Opportunity ID?

Comment: Ohhh sorry my bad. So what I did is like this temp.ID = opportunityID;

Comment: @JMDF I'm not entirely sure you might be confusing RecordTypeId and Id, which are two different fields. Using clone would keep the RecordTypeId from the original record. If you're cloning a record, it gets a new Id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47348/discussion-between-jmdf-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: Well basically one of the requirements is Update the new cloned record’s record type = “LPG – EU VSP Opportunity”. 

I Tried doing this temp.RecordTypeName = "LPG – EU VSP Opportunity"; But it throws an error.